I'm no longer able to connect to the internet using iptables
Good afternoon. Here is a diagram of my home network:
            Internal
           Interface   
x.x.1.14    x.x.1.99                     
---------   ---------   ---------   ----------
|       |   |       |   |       |   |        |
| Comp1 |---|Rasp Pi|---|Router |---|Internet|
|       |   |       | | |       |   |        |
---------   --------- | ---------   ----------
            x.x.0.123 |   x.x.0.1      8.8.8.8
            External  |
           Interface  | ---------
                      | |       |
                      |-| Comp2 |
                        |       |
                        ---------
                        x.x.0.135


I connected two networks at home (one WiFi and one wired) running iptables on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on a Raspberry Pi. From Comp1 I was able to ping Comp2 and the internet, but then I did something foolish on my Pi (changed the root password and tossed the sticky-note) and had to redo my Pi. I redid the Pi, with the same network settings, and now I can ping Comp2 from Comp1 again, but not the internet. I have a plethora of notes that I typed when trying to get the Pi to work the first time, but nothing I have done thus far has given me connectivity to the internet. Here is a list of what I've tried so far:
Nope
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.0.123 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.0.123 -o 192.168.1.99 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.1.99 -o 192.168.0.123 -j ACCEPT

Nope
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.0.123 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.1.99 -o 192.168.0.123 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.0.123 -o 192.168.1.99 -j ACCEPT

Nope
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.1.99 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.0.123 -o 192.168.1.99 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.1.99 -o 192.168.0.123 -j ACCEPT

Nope
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.1.99 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.1.99 -o 192.168.0.123 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.0.123 -o 192.168.1.99 -j ACCEPT

Nope
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

Nope
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.0.123 -o 192.168.1.99 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.1.99 -o 192.168.0.123 -j ACCEPT

Nope
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

Nope
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

I also added the route to the second network on the Linux box:
$ sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.99

I tried the flip-flops because the first time around I made a mistake and flip-flopped the the IP labels on what I found on the internet and it worked. SO, can anyone see what I did wrong, or what I'm missing?
Thanks,
Joe

and thanks for the quick response. Ok, here's the information:
Comp1 - Linux
ens160 is 192.168.1.14
Pi - Linux
eth0 is 192.168.1.99
wlan0 is 192.168.0.123
Comp2 - Windows
192.168.0.135
iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Tue Nov 26 12:54:31 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [204777:66752196]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Nov 26 12:54:31 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Tue Nov 26 12:54:31 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [117749:8274546]
-A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.0.123 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.0.123 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Nov 26 12:54:31 2024

Joe

And the output of sysctl -p:
jfxb@Pi5:~$ sudo sysctl -p
[sudo] password for jfxb:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
jfxb@Pi5:~$


It'd be nice to know the ethernet interface names on each system.  Can you also just dump all your iptables rules with iptables-save please on the RPi?  Copy them into your post as an edit and if you can apply code formatting to it so it's readable.  Also the output of sysctl -p as well, because you might not have IP forwarding enabled by default which is necessary to work with IP forwarding like this.

You are incorrectly entering the iptables rule for the nat table. In all of your examples, you are using an IP address instead of an interface name for the -o option.
Looking at the manpage for iptables(8):

[!] -o, --out-interface name
              Name of an interface via which a packet is going to be sent (for  packets  entering
              the  FORWARD, OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains).  When the "!" argument is used before
              the interface name, the sense is inverted.  If the interface name ends  in  a  "+",
              then  any  interface  which  begins  with  this name will match.  If this option is
              omitted, any interface name will match.


Your first example is incorrectly entered as follows:
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.0.123 -j MASQUERADE

Therefore, change the IP address to an interface name. For your setup, the interface connected to the router with an IP address of 192.168.0.123 is wlan0.
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE


According to the output of iptables-save that you provided in your post, your default policy for the INPUT, OUTPUT, and FORWARD chains is ACCEPT. Therefore, the FORWARD rules you've defined are unnecessary:
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT

You also have two incorrect rules in your nat table:
-A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.0.123 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o 192.168.0.123 -j MASQUERADE

So before entering the correct nat rule, flush all chains:
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -F -t nat

To make your iptables rules persistent at each reboot, you'll need to first install iptables-persistent:
sudo apt install iptables-persistent

Then, save your current rules:
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"


Finally, it appears that you've already enabled IP forward within the kernel, but I'll add it here to be complete:
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"


Wow, thanks mpboden - I'm back up and running! I guess the "flip-flop" was with the interface name.

@thomas ward - Ahhhhhhhh, ethernet interface names. Now I get it.
